# Adding fields to a CKAN organization

Tags: ckan

The idea is to use CKAN as member database. To do this I need to add more fields.  I have a prototype here https://codepen.io/terchris/full/PQjgxB/ and picture below.
[prototype picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JDGu.png)

I want the admin of the organization to be able to update the fields for their organization and add users that belong to the organization. The role and access right system in CKAN seems to handle this just fine. So I just need a way to add extra fields to the CKAN organization.

The API for reading organizations from CKAN http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/#ckan.logic.action.get.organization_list
 has a parameter (include_extras) that indicates that it is possible to get the added fields.

From reading the API doc it seems that it is possible to tag (include_tags) an organization and to make it member of a group (include_groups). But I cannot see anywhere in the web admin page related to add tags or groups to an organization.

I can find CKAN doc about adding extra fields to datasets. http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html
But not to organizations and users.

Is it possible to add fields to organization and user ?

The fields in the prototype are as follows

```
{
    name: "AiSpot",
    orgType: "Startup",
    slogan: "IoT og app for varehandel og reiseliv",
    website: "https://aispot.no/",
    logoURL: "http://urbalurba.no/dataset/27695b10-8987-42d4-87ce-e0a172293cd4/resource/419ecbe2-3432-47c2-936f-53a4e979b519/download/aispot-400x200.png",
    segments: ["Mobilitet"],
    tags: ["Programvare"],
    longTXT: "Aispot helps retail and destinations engage customers and increase loyalty. Enabling the concept of Future Shopping. Clients Simply connect to – and publish to their customers through a shared mobile platform utilizing beacons, QR, club, mobile Wallet and a range of ready-made services",
    contacts: [
        {
            contactName: "Harald Jellum",
            contactTitle: "Gründer",
            contactAvatarURL: "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_400_400/AAMAAQDuAAgAAQAAAAAAABAkAAAAJGE1ZjIyZWM3LTg1NDItNGQ5Yy05MDVmLWVmM2FmMDc3NmVlYg.bin",
            contactLinkedinURL: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/grunderfabrikken/"
        }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is currently not possible to add tags and "extra" fields to groups and organizations. This functionality was intended but never fully implemented (hence the `include_extras` and `include_tags` parameters which don't actually do anything). See [this ticket](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/4388) for details.

The [ckanext-scheming](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-scheming) extension provides `scheming_groups` and `scheming_organization` plugins which could in theory be used to extend groups and organizations with custom fields. However, these extended variants would not automatically replace the original groups and organization objects in other parts of CKAN.

One way to accomplish your goal would be to store the necessary information in a separate database table. For example, [ckanext-extractor](https://github.com/stadt-karlsruhe/ckanext-extractor) stores resource metadata not in the resource itself but in a separate table.

Comment: I am using happily `scheming_organization`. Could you please elaborate what restrictions you seem to referring to with *would not automatically replace the original groups and organization objects in other parts of CKAN*? Tnx.

Comment: @hvwaldow: I am not using `scheming_organization` myself, so I might be wrong, but my impression was that you could use `scheming_organization` to create a new type of organization, separate from the existing one, and that the existing CKAN infrastructure (e.g. package ownership) would continue to use the original organization type. But as I said that may very well be completely untrue. Perhaps you could contribute a bit of documentation or some sample code for `scheming_organization` to ckanext-scheming? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Florian! I think you are right that you can indeed define a different organization type the handling of which would need to implemented separately in the rest of CKAN (just like for a different `dataset_type`. However, if you use `organization_type": "organization"`in the definition of the organization-schema, then, analogous to `dataset`, the original schema is replaced and, apparently, seamlessly used. Yes, it's underdocumented.

Comment: Here is [my organization schema](https://github.com/eawag-rdm/ckanext_eaw_schema/blob/master/ckanext/eaw_schema/eaw_schema_organization.json).

Comment: This goes into `production.ini`: `ckan.plugins = scheming_organizations` ; `scheming.organization_schemas = ckanext.eaw_schema:eaw_schema_organization.json`